# Est-ce que « Nous passons notre temps à nous quereller sur mes habitudes alimentaires » est correct ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

Est-ce que l’énonciation en question se dit et répond au bon usage. L’emploi de la préposition « sur » après le verbe « se quereller » me laisse hésitant, j’ignore si cette construction est d’usage et surtout si elle est idiomatique. J’avais aussi à l’idée de contourner cette difficulté en écrivant plutôt « à cause de mes habitudes alimentaires », mais encore ici il m’est impossible de lever mon hésitation. Merci.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

J'utiliserais plutôt *à propos* :

> Nous passons notre temps à nous quereller à propos de mes habitudes alimentaires.

ou le moins soutenu :

> On passe notre temps à se quereller à propos de mes habitudes alimentaires.

Comment: Je trouve "quereller" quoi qu'il en soit relativement soutenu... "s'embrouiller", "s'engueuler", "se chamailler", semblent fonctionner aussi dans un registre plus familier. "sur", bien que sans doute moins correct, me semble aussi plus familier. Je pourrais assez facilement m'imaginer dire "On passe notre temps à s'embrouiller sur mes habitudes alimentaires"

Comment: @Oui, j'ai mis *moins soutenu* car la deuxième l'est encore, mais peut-être qu'au Québec le registre de *se quereller* n'est pas aussi soutenu qu'il ne l'est en français européen.

Comment: Pas faux en effet...

Answer (score 0):

Bonjour ...oui l'expression est tout a fait correcte et soutenue comme il faut...En plus ca fait tres classe !